# Luggage with multiple long flights

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, international-travel

I will travel from Sacramento to Prague via Los Angeles and Paris with a single airticket from Delta.
Do I need to take my luggage in LA and recheck or I'll give my luggage in Sacramento and get in Prague?

Comment: When you check in at Sacramento.  Your bag will be sitting on the conveyor belt as you are checked in. Look the check-in staff member in the eye and say very clearly "Are you checking my baggage all the way through to Prague?"  The person should say "Yes".  Then, look at the long stickers they have attached (likely to the handle of your luggage).  ***IT WILL SHOW YOU WHERE IT IS CHECKED THROUGH TO***, it should say "PRG".  Point to that, and ask again "Does this mean it is going all the way to Prague, I won't see it until Prague?"  They should say "yes that is correct!"

Answer (score 1):

Providing this is on a single ticket, you will check in your luggage in Sacramento and pick it up in Prague. When you check your luggage in, you will see the final destination printed on the luggage tag, which will be PRG.

On the return, assuming you're following the same route, you will need to pick up your luggage in LA and carry to the transfer belt after going through customs.